# how to seperate string and integer values from the file and store it into a variable using java program

Tags: java, text-parsing

i had a notepad file with 
tea--10.00
coffee--20.00
bread--30.00.how to seperate tea,coffee,bread strings to an arrayList and seperate ineger values and storing to another variables.i need to program in java.i programmed like this

```
 package sample_god1;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class filedata_retive_seperateVlaues 
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
       int var;
       String var2;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("222.txt"));
       while(sc.hasNextLine())
      {
        String[] mnu=sc.nextLine().split("--");
        int[] nums=new int[mnu.length];
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(var[i]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Double> prices = new ArrayList<>();
  while(sc.hasNextLine())
  {
    String[] mnu=sc.nextLine().split("--");
    int[] nums=new int[mnu.length];
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
       items.add(mnu[0]);
       prices.add(Double.parseDouble(mnu[1]));
     }
  }
```

Instead of two separate list you should have a map ,

```
 map.put(mnu[0],Double.parseDouble(mnu[1]));
```

Comment: List <String> items=new ArrayList<>();
    List <Double> prices=new ArrayList<>(); these line shown as a error in eclipse like "The type list is not generic it cannot be parameterized arguments"

Comment: what is the java version?